# Ruby on Rails: How do I execute a function before saving to the database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to alter the data and save it then to the database when using the new / create function of the app.

Comment: Do you want to do it app-wide or model-specific?

Comment: should be just in the model like in the answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use active callbacks, as the two other answers stated. The *before_create* is definitely the one you are looking for. Always do that kind of logic in the model, and not in the controller. Rails mantra (one of many) is "thin controller, fat model", which enable code reuse more easily.

You can check the active callbacks documentation at :

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Also, here is an example of what you want to achieve

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_create :alter_my_data

    def alter_my_data
        # any manipulation you want to do here before saving
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks also for the link (but they should fix the tpyo there, some text parts are hard to read because the text size is too small)

Comment: I agree! ctrl + mousewheel up to upsize text ;-)

Answer (score 4):

```
before_create :myfunction

def myfunction
  # Edit data
end
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: thanks, the whole big ruby on rails documentation is really huge but ruby on rails itself with scaffolding is easy =)

Answer (score 0):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :validate_username

  def validate_username
    raise "blank error" if username.blank?
    #....your code
  end
end
```

Comment: Raising exceptions in a validation method? Really?

Answer (score 0):

Your question has already been answered above, but I really recommend you check out the official Ruby on Rails guides:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

The guides are easy to comprehend and cover many parts of Rails. Your question is answered in the 'Active Record Validations and Callbacks' section.

Comment: i checked them out but did you work with ruby on rails the first time and scaffolding and had there a huuuuuuuge documentation for ruby (on rails) and no plan what to do next while you have to write a whole app from scratch new in a few days?  how should i know that this is there at active record validations and call backs? i already know active record and all the other stuff but didnt know where to search, for what to search and how to do it.